# ProGuard exclude a jar file

Tags: gradle, android-proguard

i have two build variants in my project and they use their own pro guard rules.
One build variant requires a Jar file, while the other one doesn't need it.

So i wanna configure the pro guard to not to include the  jar file , while building the second build variant.
Not sure if it possible, but if it is i wanna know.

In Short: I wanna remove a jar file completely using the pro guard.

P.s.i recently reached 65K limit. And the second build variant targets devices below 4.0. So removing unused Jar file will reduce the method count.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what im looking for but its an option.

Defining build variant dependencies in your gradle script will help.

I still didnt find a way to remove it with pro guard though